# Button border color will not change to custom color

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I have a very simple transparent button subclass, and I am trying to change the border to be the same color as the text, however it turns out white.

```
class transparentButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupButton()
    }
    
    // Setup the button
    func setupButton() {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3
        self.layer.borderColor = CGColor(red: 203, green: 72, blue: 75, alpha: 0.75)
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CGColor` init takes in values from **0** to **1**, as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolor/1455631-init) says:

<kbd>[image: Parameters of CGColor init, which shows that each value must be between 0.0 t0 1.0]</kbd>

Instead of being out of **255** as you might be used to, the maximum value is **1**. If you supply a value that is over **1**, I assume it just caps down to **1**, which means that:

```
CGColor(red: 203, green: 72, blue: 75, alpha: 0.75)
```

turns into...

```
CGColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.75)
```

...which is a white color.

So, you must divide everything by **255**.

```
func setupButton() {
   self.backgroundColor = .clear
   self.layer.borderWidth = 3   
   self.layer.borderColor = CGColor(red: 203 / 255, green: 72 / 255, blue: 75 / 255, alpha: 0.75)
}
```

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |